# Contar vocales Java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa con el que tienes que introducir una frase terminada en punto y te tiene que decir por ejemplo la vocal "a" sale en la posición 7 y asi con todas la vocales.
La primera parte que sea una frase teminada en punto la he echo bien. Pero luego la parte en la que tienes que buscar las vocales no me funciona bien.

```
    String texto;
    int c;

    System.out.println("Introduce un texto terminado en punto:");
    texto="";
    do{
        texto=texto+ent.nextLine().trim();
        if(!texto.endsWith(".")) texto+="\n";
    }while(texto.charAt(texto.length()-1)!='.');
    String cadena="aeiou";
        for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++){
            int b = 0;
            b++;
            String a;
            a=cadena.charAt(b);
          System.out.format("\n%d caracter %c",i,text.charAt(a));  
        }
```

Este es el error que me muestra:

> error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String
>   a=cadena.charAt(b); error: incompatible types: String cannot be
>   converted to int System.out.format("\n%d caracter
>   %c",i,text.charAt(a));

Pero si pongo char ademas de String peta igualmente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error lo tenés en estas líneas:

```
String a;
a=cadena.charAt(b);
```

Acá es donde estas intentando asignar un `char` a un `String`.

Si `a` tiene que ser un `String` entonces podés hacer:

```
String a;
a = "" + cadena.charAt(b);
```

Y si tiene que ser un `char` entonces:

```
char a;
a=cadena.charAt(b);
```

Cual elijas depende de como vas a uar `a`

Por otro lado:

`text.charAt(a)` es incorrecto ya sea que a sea un `char` o un `String`.
En `charAt(x)`, `x` es un número que indica la posición del caracter dentro del `String`.

Si `a` fuera un `char` (en las opciones de arriba) se podría escribir:

```
System.out.format("\n%d caracter %c",i, a );
```

> Pero con System.out.format("\n%d caracter %c",i, a ); no funcionaria
>   bien porque lo importante es filtrar para ver las vocales. Si el
>   charAt(), no es correcto que metodo para filtrar utilizo?

El programa, hasta donde está hecho, si se corrigen los errores, cicla por cada letra de la palabra o frase, pero no hace ningún tipo de inspección o filtrado.

Lo que te queda por hacer es verificar, en cada ciclo, si la letra es una vocal, y si es así contarla.

Luego, al salir de ciclo (cuando ya se insepeccionaron todas la letras) imprimir la cantidad para cada vocal.

Como ayuda, vas a necesitar 5 contadores que arrancan en cero, uno para cada vocal. Lo podés implementar tanto como 5 variables separadas o en un vector donde la posición 0 sea la a y la posición 4 la u.

@gbianchi encontró otros errores en el ciclo for relacionado a la variable `b` siendo reinicializada en cada ciclo. Además de que estás usando un solo `for` para hacer algo que en realidad requiere dos `for` anidados.

Para poder ciclar por todas las vocales para cada letra del texto necesitas un `for` como este:

```
// Este ciclo recorre el texto ingresado
for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++){
        // El caracter del texto en la posición actual
        char caracterTexto = texto.charAt(i);
        //Este for recorre cada vocal para cada letra del texto ingresado
        for(int b=0 ; b<cadena.length(); b++){
            char a;
            a=cadena.charAt(b);
            System.out.format("\n%d caracter %c",i,a); 
            // Agregar aca la verificación del caracterTexto vs cada vocal (a)
            // Y contar en el contador correspondiente
        }            
}
// En este punto ya están contadas todas las vocales del texto
// Acá se imprime el resultado acumulado en cada uno de los contadores
```

Comment: Pero con System.out.format("\n%d caracter %c",i, a ); no funcionaria bien porque lo importante es filtrar para ver las vocales. Si el charAt(), no es correcto que metodo para filtrar utilizo?

Comment: Ahí, justo actualicé la respuesta... @gbianchi

Comment: @gbianchi es así, 0 a length - 1. si se me escapó algo no lo estoy viendo.

Comment: tenes razon no dije nada porque pusiste <.. mi error...

Comment: Muchas gracias! Eres un crack! Ya me funciona bien ahora la unica duda que me queda es que por ejemplo si filtro la vocal a y tengo el texto Buenàs tardes(es un ejemplo se que no va con acento xd) me coge la letra à igualmente si solo quiero que me coja la letra sin acento como lo hago?

Comment: @Pepe, Si esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, por favor recuerda [acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Leyendo el comentario, veo que tienes otra pregunta, para ello, debes crear una nueva pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Este algoritmo permite determinar la posición de las vocales dentro de un texto siempre que cumpla con la condición que termine en un punto.

```
public void posicionVocales(String texto){
    if(!texto.endsWith(".")) {
      System.out.println("El texto no cumple los requisitos. Falta el \".\"");
    }else{ // Se hacen las operaciones normales de localizar las vocales y colocar su posicion
        char arregloLetras[] = texto.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        int posicion = 0;
                             // a e i o u
        int vecesRepetidas[] = {0,0,0,0,0};

        for(char letra : arregloLetras){
           switch(letra){
               case 97: // Vocal a
                   System.out.println("Vocal: "+letra+" Posicion-> "+posicion);
                   vecesRepetidas[0] += 1;
                   break;
               case 101: // Vocal e
                   System.out.println("Vocal: "+letra+" Posicion-> "+posicion);
                   vecesRepetidas[1] += 1;
                   break;    
               case 105: // Vocal i
                   System.out.println("Vocal: "+letra+" Posicion-> "+posicion);
                   vecesRepetidas[2] += 1;
                   break;    
               case 111: // Vocal o
                   System.out.println("Vocal: "+letra+" Posicion-> "+posicion);
                   vecesRepetidas[3] += 1;
                   break;    
               case 117: // Vocal u
                   System.out.println("Vocal: "+letra+" Posicion-> "+posicion);
                   vecesRepetidas[4] += 1;
                   break; 
               default :
                   System.out.println("Rechazado: "+letra);
                   break;

           }

           posicion++;
        }

        System.out.println("----------NRO DE APARICIONES------------\n"+
                "a = "+vecesRepetidas[0]+"\n"+
                "e = "+vecesRepetidas[1]+"\n"+
                "i = "+vecesRepetidas[2]+"\n"+
                "o = "+vecesRepetidas[3]+"\n"+
                "u = "+vecesRepetidas[4]       
                        );
    }

}
```

Luego se ejecuta el método dentro de una instancia

```
pm.posicionVocales("Esta es una historia de vocales.");
```

Y los resultados para el ejemplo serian los siguientes:

Vocal: e Posicion-> 0 
Rechazado: s 
Rechazado: t 
Vocal: a Posicion-> 3 
Rechazado:  
Vocal: e Posicion-> 5
Rechazado: s
Rechazado:  
Vocal: u Posicion-> 8
Rechazado: n
Vocal: a Posicion-> 10
Rechazado:  
Rechazado: h
Vocal: i Posicion-> 13
Rechazado: s
Rechazado: t
Vocal: o Posicion-> 16
Rechazado: r
Vocal: i Posicion-> 18
Vocal: a Posicion-> 19
Rechazado:  
Rechazado: d
Vocal: e Posicion-> 22
Rechazado:  
Rechazado: v
Vocal: o Posicion-> 25
Rechazado: c
Vocal: a Posicion-> 27
Rechazado: l
Vocal: e Posicion-> 29
Rechazado: s
Rechazado: .
----------NRO DE APARICIONES------------
a = 4
e = 4
i = 2
o = 2
u = 1

Comment: En general cuando un usuario pregunta por un ejercicio, mas que resolverlo tratamos de ayudarlo a que lo entienda para que pueda resolverlo por si mismo. Tu respuesta es correcta. Salvo por el detalle que no cuenta la cantidad de vocales repetidas ;)

Comment: Ya se agrego el nro de veces que aparecen cada vocal.

Answer (score 0):

creo que está es la más fácil de todas.

```
char[] var ="asdfasffae".toCharArray();
int pos = 0;

        for(char x: var) {
            switch(x) {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                System.out.println( x + " en la posicion: " + pos);
            }
            pos++;
        }
```

y produce el siguiente resultado

```
a en la posicion: 0
a en la posicion: 4
a en la posicion: 8
e en la posicion: 9
```

Acá la explicación:
dentro del for tomas una carácter de la cadena y entras dentro del switch el cual verifica si es una vocal en los case. De ser así imprime el valor del carácter y la posición.

Comment: si es mas fácil debes explicarla, no solo poner el código

Comment: Y si la vocal es mayúscula? faltaría que agregues las veces que aparece cada vocal.

Comment: si exacto solo debes agregar los casos extras.